# Integrating $\frac{1}{(1-x)^2} $ into two different-looking functions

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, indefinite-integrals

**Background**

I want to "trick" some students by showing that $$\int \frac{1}{(1-x)^2} \mathrm dx = \frac1{1-x} + C$$ in one instance and $$\int \frac{1}{(1-x)^2} \mathrm dx = \frac x{1-x} + C$$ in another.

Obviously these look like two different results due to the different numerator, but as the more astute will point out, the difference between these functions is a constant, and they therefore have the same derivative.

**Question**

When solving the integral, using the substitution $u = 1-x$ we naturally arrive that the first results, but is there a way of solving the integral that "naturally" yields the second result?

Comment: You may try showing that $$\dfrac{1}{(1-x)^2}=1+2x+3x^2+\cdots $$ and then integrate both sides, RHS will result in $\dfrac{x}{1-x}$. But of course, this method is only valid for $|x|<1$.

Comment: Maybe another point can be put into the lesson.  Do the two integrals, but "forget" to write $+C$ on them.  After you are done, and show the two answers differ by a constant, you can tell them to remember $+C$ in the future, to avoid this confusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not get them to differentiate $$\frac{x}{1-x}$$ using the quotient rule:

$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right) = \frac{1.(1-x) - (-1).x}{(1-x)^2}$$ which simplifies very naturally to give$$\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}.$$

This would imply $$\int \frac{1}{(1-x)^2} \mathrm dx = \frac x{1-x} + C$$

Comment: No, I disagree. Read his question and my answer again. My suggestion is a "natural way" to get to the second result in the question.

Comment: Yeah, I like this one. Pretty much the first way I teach integrals is as "antiderivatives", and how you can "solve" an indefinite integral by differentiating the expected result and showing that it equals the integrand. I could phrase the "trick" as having them differentiate the second form first, and solving the integral with the $u$-sub afterwards. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Put $x=\sin^2(t)$; then $dx = 2\sin(t)\cos(t)\,dt$. We have
$$
\int \frac{1}{(1-x)^2}\,dx \longrightarrow \int \frac{2\sin(t)\cos(t)}{(1-\sin^2(t))^2}\,dt
$$
$$
=2\int \frac{\sin(t)}{\cos^3(t)}\,dt = 2\int \tan(t)\sec^2(t)\,dt  
$$
$$
\begin{cases}\stackrel{y=\tan(t)}{\longrightarrow}\int 2y\,dy= \tan^2(t)+C = \frac{\sin^2(t)}{1-\sin^2(t)}+C\longrightarrow \frac{x}{1-x}+C\\
\stackrel{y=\sec(t)}{\longrightarrow}\int 2y\,dy=  \sec^2(t)+C = \frac{1}{1-\sin^2(t)}+C\longrightarrow \frac{1}{1-x}+C
\end{cases}
$$This is a general phenomenon: antiderivatives of trig functions involving tangent and secant often look dissimilar but by the FTC they must be identical up to a constant.